# Getting a ModuleNotFound error with flask in python

Tags: python-3.x, flask, web, pip, routes

I installed the `flask` module via following command.[![cmd image][1]][1]
When I ran the following code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    #a = input('Enter name')
    return render_template(r'form.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=True)
```

It gave an error.
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'`

Note:- I am not using `virtualenv`. And I am having my `html` page in `templates` folder
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4XzJ.png

Comment: The command with which you installed Flask is not visible.

Comment: The url at last has the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have installed flask on the system wide environment. To access the flask in your virtualenv, you have to get into the virtualenv directory and activate it by using following command.

```
source virtual_env_name/bin/activate
```

replace 'virtual_env_name' with the virtualenv name you created.
After that in your command line, you will get `(virtual_env_name)` added before. the current directory path.

Now you can install the flask framework using pip3.

```
pip3 install flask
```

Keep in mind to activate venv everytime you are using the flask.